# Which is why not calculated values well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/contact/)

I made a div width calculation but unfortunately my values are not correctly calculated and automatically div is more than should be.

Look at the picture below to see what I mean ..

[image]

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
  var windowsizecontact = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  console.log("ecran contact:",windowsizecontact);
  var stanga= jQuery('.contact-stanga').outerWidth();
  console.log("latime-stanga:",stanga);  
  var dreapta= jQuery('.contact-dreapta').outerWidth();  
  console.log("latime-dreapta:",dreapta);  
  var contentcontactwh=windowsizecontact-stanga-dreapta;
  console.log("rezultat",contentcontactwh);
  console.log("------------------");
   
  if ($("#primary").hasClass("content-contact")) {
       
     $('#primary').width(contentcontactwh);

  }

)};
```

What is the reason for not correctly calculate these values?
You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the border, padding and margin on the element. This may not be included in the width. Try using `outerWidth()`.

Comment: Well, I did not it?i don`t have border.

Comment: Both console and inspector tool give me the same result, 260px width for the current window size, in Chrome, and same result also when resizing.

Comment: Same here. In the screenshot, did you resize the window after initialisation? The JS function is only called once; the info in the console is not updated afterwards.